# TableColumn, How to connect it with property but not fill the cells

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, tablecolumn

I have a TableView and Data class with integer properties for columns. However I would like columns at first show empty cells so user can put value he wants.

Right now its impossible because when creating Data object, integer values has to be created with initial value, so table shows up filled already with numbers.

```
  private ObservableList<MyData> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

.....edited....

```
private void buttAddColumnAction(ActionEvent event){        
        int i = numberOfColumns;// thats the key for lambda expression. Unicate number for column to access its variable;

        if(dataList.size() > 0)//resizing each data object with new variable
            for(MyData x: dataList)
                x.addNew();

        TableColumn<MyData, Integer> newColumn = new TableColumn<>("#" + String.valueOf(++numberOfColumns));

        newColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCellValue(i));
    //  newColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<MyData, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));

        Callback<TableColumn<MyData, Integer>, TableCell<MyData, Integer>> cellFactoryInt = (TableColumn<MyData, Integer> p) -> new EditingCellNumbers(tableView);
        newColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryInt);
        tableView.getColumns().add(newColumn);

    }


public class MyData{ //dont forget about public because you wont get acces to properties
    private ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Integer>> cellValue = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MyData(int howManyColumns) {
        for(int i=0; i<howManyColumns; ++i)
           this.cellValue.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(null));
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Integer> getCellValue(int whichOne) {
        return cellValue.get(whichOne);
    }

    public void setCellValue(int cellValue, int whichOne) {
        this.cellValue.set(whichOne, new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(cellValue));
    }

    public void addNew(){ //ads another variable for another column
        cellValue.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(null));
    }
    public void deleteLast(){ //deletes last variable when column is deleted
        cellValue.remove(cellValue.size()-1);
    }
}


CellFactory



//Klasa ta pozwala na definiowania zachowania komórek, które edytuje użytkownik
    public class EditingCellNumbers extends TableCell<MyData, Integer>{ 
    private TextField textField;
    private TableView<MyData> parentTableView;
    public static int numberOfColumns;

    public EditingCellNumbers(TableView<MyData> parent) {
        this.parentTableView = parent;
        numberOfColumns = parent.getColumns().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit(){
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());

                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
            Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
                if (!arg2) {
         XXX           commitEdit(Integer.valueOf(textField.getText()));
                }
        });
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                try{
                    int i = Integer.valueOf(textField.getText());
                    //digit given...
                    if( (i>=0) && (i<10) ){//making sure cell is filled with just one digit
                       commitEdit(Integer.valueOf(textField.getText()));
                       int selectedColumn = parentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getColumn(); // gets the number of selected column
                       int selectedRow = parentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
                       if(selectedColumn < numberOfColumns-1){
                           parentTableView.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
                           parentTableView.edit(selectedRow, parentTableView.getColumns().get(selectedColumn+1));
                       }else{
                           parentTableView.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow+1, parentTableView.getColumns().get(0));
                           parentTableView.edit(selectedRow+1, parentTableView.getColumns().get(0));

                       }

                    }else
                       textField.clear();
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    textField.clear();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: let the custom cell show nothing if the value is 0 (or isn't yet initialized, requires a little bit of additional logic)

Comment: I dont know how to make cells show nothing....

Comment: @Tomek `setText(null)` in your renderer?

Comment: Im not sure where is this rendering stuff ...EDIT... okay... updateItem()

Comment: exactly :-) don't forget to call super.updateItem

Comment: You can actually do this without a custom cell factory, just using the standard `TextFieldTableCell`. Just 1. allow the values to be `null` using a `ObjectProperty<Integer>` instead of an `IntegerProperty` and 2. use a custom `StringConverter`

Answer (score 2):

Allow `null` values in your column by using an `ObjectProperty<Integer>` instead of an `IntegerProperty`. This gives a more natural way to define "not initialized" than representing it with 0 (or some other proxy value).

Then you can use the `TextFieldTableCell`, but just supply a custom `StringConverter<Integer>`:

```
public class MyData{ //dont forget about public because you wont get acces to properties
    private ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Integer>> cellValue = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MyData(int howManyColumns) {
        for(int i=0; i<howManyColumns; ++i)
           this.cellValue.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Random().nextInt(10)));
    }

 // ...
}
```

and

```
    newColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCellValue(i));
    newColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<MyData, Integer>forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Integer i) {
        if (i == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else {
            return i.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String string) {
        if (string.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null ;
        } else {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(string);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null ;
            } 
        }
    }
}));
```

Complete example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class TableViewWithEmptyIntegerColumn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = createCol("Name", Item::nameProperty);
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> valueCol = createCol("Value", Item::valueProperty);
        valueCol.setEditable(true);

        valueCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer i) {
                if (i == null) {
                    return "" ;
                } else {
                    return i.toString() ;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                if (string.trim().length() == 0) {
                    return null ;
                } else {
                    // better to check for a valid int format instead of using try-catch...
                    try {
                        return Integer.valueOf(string);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        return null ;
                    }
                }
            }

        }));

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
            if (rng.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
                table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i));
            } else {
                table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(10)+1));
            }
        }

        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, valueCol);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 400, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createCol(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final ObjectProperty<Integer> value = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Item(String name, Integer value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public Item(String name) {
            this(name, null);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<Integer> valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final Integer getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final Integer value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the standard `IntegerStringConverter` even seems to work here, though it doesn't handle non-integer, non-blank values elegantly.

Comment: it seems to be working, hovewer with my cell factory(which I need) it gives me lot of trouble when editing, and Im not sure I can handle it.

Comment: You'll probably need to post the code for your cell implementation

Comment: see the edit. Right now when I put empty cell to edit, and then cancel it, compiler gives NumberFormatException at place marked with XXX

Comment: and cell displays "null"

Comment: You need to check that you have a valid number when you call `commitEdit(...)` and pass some default value (`null`) otherwise (same logic as my converter's `fromString(...)` method).

Comment: I just did: `if(getItem() != null)
                  commitEdit(Integer.valueOf(textField.getText()));
                 else
                       commitEdit(null);`  and seems to be working